# Facebook and twitter icons stacked up?

Tags: css, wordpress

On our website, the Facebook and Twitter icons are stacked on top of each other. We're using wordpress for the site, and the CSS makes sense, but it isn't updating / doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Heres the CSS:

```css
#fb {
  z-index: 999999;
  bottom: 70px;
  right: 220px;
}
#twitter {
  z-index: 999999;
  bottom: 70px;
  right: 220px;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your two icons are positioned in the same location. Please include your HTML code to help demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. Two CSS rules does not an example make.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can using the `position: absolute` so stack up two iocns

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/aqcq21nh/